# Saving base64 string as PDF at client side Internet Explorer 10 and above

Tags: html, pdf, base64, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I am working on Saving base64 string as PDF at client side using  'data:application/pdf;base64,' with JavaScript.
For Example Anchor tag for Download PDF on browser looks  like this :

```
<a id="openPdf" rel="openPdf" href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KMSAwIG9iago8PAobQogL0ltM==" download="1199_07112014_P.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

(The above HTML snippet data is deleted so its not a valid pdf )

It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but its breaking in IE10 and above.

Can anyone please suggest to find a solution on this?